# Azure API - Unable to access API gateway Url from API Management

Tags: c#, azure, postman, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I used the open specification to create API and completed settings for OAuth2.0 with the certificate to access API. I have tried to access the Gateway URL of API from Postman, but it shows { "statusCode": 401, "message": "Unauthorized. The access token is invalid. " }

Gateway URL is like this "https://xxxx.azure-api.net/todo/api/todolist"

Please guide on how to access the API Gateway URL.

Please check the file. I have added configuration details.

API settings

[image]

Oauth2.0 setting

[image]

Policy

[image]

Comment: This question required some information. Like how you configured. What is your gateway  and api ? Authentication configured at which point ?

Comment: @dotnetstep Please check attached files.

Comment: COuld you please tell me how you get token?

Comment: @JimXu I have set all Oauth2.0 settings in postman and clicked on the "Get token button". By clicking the Get Token button, I get the bearer token, which I used to send. Also added Certificate in postman, that certificate also added into API management.

Comment: COuld you please parse your token via https://jwt.ms and validate the claims you define in policy/

Comment: @JimXu Thanks for great help! My problem is resolved.

Comment: @Ukstest Since your issue has been resolved by yourself, could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved with help of @JimXu comment.
Checked generated access token by [jwt.ms](http://jwt.ms) and made changes in Azure inbound policy. Checked that audience, issuer, Claim values were correct and matching.